# toaster with html and angular ng-bind in it?

Tags: angularjs, toast

Im having trouble doing simple toaster msg with angular and html, like this:

```
 toaster.pop('success','','<span data-ng-bind="item.onSelect.msg"></span>',null,'trustedHtml');
```

the item.onSelect.msg is of type string, it's not working...moreover i tried te following:

```
 toaster.pop('success','','<span> item.onSelect.msg</span>',null,'trustedHtml');
```

And

```
   toaster.pop('success','','<span> {{item.onSelect.msg}}</span>',null,'trustedHtml');
```

The problem still persist, any ideas?

Comment: Try just doing `'<span>' + item.onSelect.msg + '</span>'`